# SwiftUI: Remove background of dragged view

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui

I have a view with rounded corners that can be dragged. Once dragging begins, a white semi-transparent background view becomes visible in the corners. How can this be removed?

I tried using `.contentShape` and `.clipShape` but this does not solve the problem. In UIKit I used `UIDragPreviewParameters` to clip the preview but there seems to be nothing like this in SwiftUI. Any ideas?

Code:

```
RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25, style: .continuous)
    .foregroundColor(.blue)
    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
    .contentShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25, style: .continuous))
    .onDrag {
        NSItemProvider()
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need `.dragPreview` type for content shape, like

```
RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25, style: .continuous)
    .foregroundColor(.blue)
    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
    .contentShape(.dragPreview, RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25, style: .continuous))
```